# Mysql 2 date type

Tags: php, mysql

Can I use 2 **date type** in 1 mysql table? because for some reason when I insert records for 2 different dates it doesnt work, only the first date is working the other one shows 00-00-00?

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: On the line 75 you can see how I insert it in this page:
https://github.com/toocool/Falco/blob/master/classes/controller.php

Comment: the first date field declared in a table is often identified as being an automatic on-update field, which may be further clouding the issue. Show the code you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are using a TIMESTAMP data type, and you want it to default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Only one TIMESTAMP column in a table can automatically be set on INSERT or UPDATE - and by default, MySQL goes with the first one.

If you would like to have more than one TIMESTAMP column get updated automatically on INSERT or UPDATE, you will need to turn to triggers.

The [docs on the TIMESTAMP data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html) are a good read!

Edit: if this educated guess does not answer your rather vaguely-phrased question, you will probably want to update your question with an example of the queries you are running, and what exactly is happening/not happening afterward.

Comment: Here is the link: github.com/toocool/Falco/blob/master/classes/controller.php

Comment: @ToCool I'm sorry, but you'll have to do your own debugging - echo out the query that is doing the INSERT into your database, and add it to your question above.  Then, elaborate on exactly what isn't happening that you think should happen.  If you pasted your table's structure, that would also be helpful.